# Order column depending on another

Tags: r, matrix, conditional-statements

I am trying to represent a ROC curve with `ggplot` library. For this propose I have a table like this:

```
    df <- matrix(c(0.2962963, 0.2962963, 0.2962963, 0.2962963, 0.2962963,
                   0.3333333, 0.2962963, 0.3333333, 0.4444444, 0.3750000,
                   0.3828125, 0.3906250, 0.3984375, 0.4062500, 0.4140625, 
                   0.4140625, 0.4218750, 0.6718750), 
                  ncol=2, byrow = F)
```

It looks like this:

```
              [,1]      [,2]
    [1,] 0.2962963 0.3750000
    [2,] 0.2962963 0.3828125
    [3,] 0.2962963 0.3906250
    [4,] 0.2962963 0.3984375
    [5,] 0.2962963 0.4062500
    [6,] 0.3333333 0.4140625
    [7,] 0.2962963 0.4140625
    [8,] 0.3333333 0.4218750
    [9,] 0.4444444 0.6718750
```

I have defined my table so that the second column is ordered. Nevertheless, what I want is: **for equal values in the second column, order the row according to the value for the first row**; that is, the sixth and seventh column present the same value `0.4140625` but I want the seventh to be first because its value for the first column is lower.

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at `?sort` and `?order`.  Just add the first column as a second sort variable.

Comment: I guess you need `df[order(df[,2], df[,1]),]`?